# CursorAdapter for chunks of data

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am pulling in weather data for each hour of the day and I want to use a Cursor Adapter to show that data.  I want to have each row in my ListView be a whole day's worth of data but what I get in the newView / bindView is a call for each hour.  I'm not sure how to even ask for one row per day.

Comment: How is the cursor that is used in the adapter being built? If it's coming from a database query then you'll have to rework the query or possibly even your database scheme to change what each row represents.

Comment: Have you check this : http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html